# SOLR Difference between indexed=true and stored=true

Tags: java, solr

In SOLR, what is the difference between `stored=true` and `indexed=true`. I know that `stored=true` stores the actual value of the field without modifying it and `indexed=true` stores the modified value of the field for computation purposes. I would like to know, till what level it affects the performance. Does a combination of `stored=true` and `indexed=true` decrease performance of persistence and retrieval when compared to `stored =false` and `indexed=true`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`indexed = true` is needed if you like to search "over" that field. If a field is not indexed, so you can not find values/terms from that field.
Your analyzer chain runs over the data on that field, if `indexed = true`.

`stored = true` is needed if you need read the values/content of a field from the index. For example, if you like to use highlighting feature or if you like to use solr as a database, and not just as a search index. If `stored = true` means: simply store the original content and output the original content, if needed.

> I would like to know, till what level it affects the performance.

Content (stored) and index are placed in different files. So solr does not need to walk through content-files on searching, only because stored is true.

It takes some time to store the data, particularly if it is large. On the retrieval side, it depends on what you put into 'fl'. If you don't retrieve the field with 'fl', you don't incur a cost to read it.

But if the field is stored, so solr is able to print the content in the result-list (depending on your solr configuration). This means, that your result list could be much bigger (depending on you content/size of fields). Building the list and transferring the list to the client could be slower, if solr has to send the content of the stored field too.

The time for executing an search will be the same. But the whole time, that is needed by the request, is an addition of several things: searching, building result list, transferring the list to the client, etc. So storing all fields an output all the content into the result list could slower your solr request, but will not have an effect on the query time.

Comment: Can you suggest other methods to improve the performance? in my case, the persistence and retrieval is becoming slow, and we are having a configuration of 1 shard and 3 replicas, the index is used for pagination purposes (like sorting, grouping etc). We are considering to increase the number of OpenSearchers, but we read that this will create an overhead on the RAM. We are also doing a lot of Hard Commits both in Batch Jobs and in Real Time. We considered to use Soft Commits but we need "Complete Real Time" responses rather than "Near Real Time" responses.

Comment: reading this, it looks like the hard commit is the reason for the performance issue.One option is to commit the data after import with `optimize=false` option. But every update fragments your index, so you have to run an optimize in an specific interval once per houre/per day. And you can play around with the `<mergeFactor>` option.  One point is, that mostly an import/commit results in an new search handler. In this case (part of the) the cache is lost = bad performance. If you can translate from german read this http://php-solr-lucene.blogspot.de/2012/09/relatime-suche-vs-performance.html

Comment: The optimization is actually set to default, which is "10". What if we increase the number of shards? wont the performance have an impact?